# Протокол взаимодействия приложений. Сокеты

Tags: python, python-2.7

Имеется приложение П, которое работает самостоятельно. Данное приложение в своей памяти хранит некоторые данные, которые мне необходимо получить.

Допустим, я хочу получать данные через web интерфейс. У меня есть сервер на flask. Я хочу использовать приложение П в качестве источника данных.

В момент запуска определенной функции в приложении П, я создаю сокет localhost (и приложение П и сервер работают на одной системе). В момент запуска сервера, я подключаюсь к сокету, отрытому в приложении П.

На сервер каждую секунду отправляется GET запрос. В параметрах запроса указывается строка вида "var1,var2,...,varn". Эта строка с помощью split(',') разбивается на список имен переменных, значения которых нужно получить от приложения П.

Была поставлена задача разработать протокол взаимодействия сервера и приложения П через сокет.

Выбрал следующую структуру: [N0 ... N7][T0][L0 ... L22], где

N (8 бит) - номер запроса.

T (1 бит) - тип запроса GET:0/SET:1

L (23 бита) - длина данных, которые нужно принять в следующем сообщении. (наверное здесь будет использоваться len(pickle.dumps(список_переменных_после_сплит)))

После этого идут данные.

Вопрос: как правильно передавать биты в сокет? Ведь socket.send принимает только объекты типа bytes. Например, как правильно в этом случае передать длину? Или нужно самому извернуться и передавать строку вида b'0xaa8000ff', а затем парсить ее?

Comment: Посмотрите модуль [struct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) - он позволяет "упаковать" данные в байты по заданному шаблону, потом распаковать по этому же шаблону. В принципе можно вообще без pickle обойтись.

Comment: Размер лучше передавать не как `b'0xaa8000ff'`, а как `b'\xff\x00\x80\xaa'` (если little endian).

Comment: unrelated comment: не смотря на структуру данных, задача выглядит как типичный pub-sub (паблишер-подписчик) процесс. Развлечения ради, можно посмотреть на celery и его аналоги, в которыхх межпроцессорное взаимодействие устроено весьма удобнейшим образом.